# How to select 2 variables from another table SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

Alright here the question

**Table 1**:

```
Id1, Id2
```

**Table 2**

```
Id, Username
```

Now this `Table 1 Id1` and `Id2` variables are unique keys in `Table 2`

I want to select `Table 1` all values as this

```
Username1, Username2
```

So how can I write this query ?

Full example

**Table 1**

```
1,3
3,5
```

**Table 2**

```
1,Furkan
3,Obama
5,USA
```

Result

```
Furkan, Obama
Obama, USA
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table2_1.Username AS Username1, table2_2.Username AS Username2
FROM table1
JOIN table2 AS table2_1 ON table1.Id1 = table2_1.Id
JOIN table2 AS table2_2 ON table1.Id2 = table2_2.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

here is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e10b7/2/0

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
     Id1 int  primary key, 
     Id2 int
);

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES (1, 3),
       (3, 5);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
     Id int  primary key, 
     Username varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (1, 'Furkan'),
       (3, 'Obama'),
       (5, 'USA');
```

Your SQL query

```
select 
    (select Username 
     from table2 as t2 
     where t2.Id = t1.Id1) as coloum1 ,
    (select Username 
     from table2 as t2 
     where t2.Id = t1.Id2) as coloum2 
from table1 as t1
```

Answer (score 1):

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a9b1/4) for live example

```
SELECT a.Username AS name_1, b.Username AS name_2 FROM
  t1 JOIN t2 AS a ON t1.Id1 = a.Id
     JOIN t2 AS b ON t1.Id2 = b.Id
```